# Realm Mobile Database and install via packagecloud.io

Tags: database, mobile, realm, platform

The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/realm/realm/linuxmint serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 1):

We don't support Linux Mint at this time.

Edit regarding the comment:

We support Linux. It's the only platform we support in production.

We support Ubuntu 16.04, CentOS 6 & 7 (as indicated on the website). You can trivially create a docker container or VM using one of these base images on Linux Mint. We have a number of issues requesting [Debian support](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/45), [Fedora support](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/1), [native Docker image](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/44), but none formally requesting Linux Mint support.

We obviously want to make the experience as painless as possible for everyone, but we also have to be very strategic when deciding to add a new platform as officially supported. Our CI has to build and test every single change on this new platform. We have to be able to support our users, etc. For example, we already have some bugs that only appear on CentOS 6, but not on 7 nor Ubuntu, so we want to make sure we stabilise things before moving ahead.

Feel free to submit a feature request to support Linux Mint. That way you will have a place where you can ask us directly about progress.

Comment: will you be doing that anytime soon? and i'd like to know what my options are as of this time you don't support linux

Comment: linuxmint serena runs on ubuntu 16.o4. shouldnt there therefore be a workaround?

Comment: i'd like to also know if i can use only mobile database then if the mobile database platform is gonna give me grief at this time. thanks

Comment: You can certainly use the Mobile Database by itself without the Mobile Platform serverside.